# Val Error, x and y must have the same dimension. [I tried to do np.array but it hasn't helped]

Tags: python, numpy

x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1, 400) and (400,)

I have search this forum and saw that people suggested to do np.array to solve this, but it didn't seem to work.

```
def function(a, v):
speedx = 0.0
yt = -1.0
val = []
for i in len(a):
    xt = a[0]
    vx = -2.0 * yt**2 * xt * (1 - xt**3) 
    vy = -2.0 * xt**2 * yt * (1 - yt**3)
    angle = np.atan2(vy,vx)
    val.append(angle)
return np.array([val])


rge = np.arange(-0.2, 0.2, 0.001)
a = np.array(rg)
speedy = 0.1 #vy

ans = odeint(function, a, speedy)

plt.plot(ans, a)
```

Comment: Please make sure you have tabbed correctly after pasting.

Comment: Show us what `function(...)` produces for one or more arguments.  Check the shape (and dtype).  Make sure you understand what it produces and what is should produce.  Review what `odeint` expects of the function.

Comment: @FirstNameBasis: Please edit the code in your question to fix the errors, so that the   code shown matches what you're actually running. Right now it's full of errors (for example, use of undefined name `rg`, use of `for i in len(a)`, which won't work, syntax errors from indentation). There's no way the code you show could produce the error you say it does, because as it stands it won't even reach the `plt.plot` line.

Answer (score 0):

When you return `np.array([val])`, that makes a two dimensional array because `val` is already an array. That is why the shape is (1,400) which makes it two dimensional with the size of the first dimension being 1. You can try:

```
return np.array(val)
```

That may help. Also, the code you have pasted has obvious bugs which I am assuming are typos like `angle.append` should have been `val.append`.

Comment: Thank you for your help but that didn't work. And I stupidly had another error there it is supposed to be plt.plot(ans, a).

Comment: It was the same. I managed to fix it though but I can't remember how I did it. I'll edit my post when I do. Thanks for the help.